# PHP Include - error in opening the stream

Tags: php, clarifai

I am using an application that I downloaded using Composer.

The package has many classes that can be called and utilized.
However, when I run the below code, I am getting the following error.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$clarifai = new \DarrynTen\Clarifai\Clarifai('CLARIFAI_API_KEY');

$input = new Input();
    $input->setImage('https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg')->isUrl();
    $inputResult = $clarifai->getInputRepository()->add($input);

echo json_encode($inputResult);
?>
```

Error:

> Warning:
>   include(/var/www/html/vendor/darrynten/clarifai-php/src/Entity):
>   failed to open stream: Not a directory in /var/www/html/ctest.php on
>   line 7
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/var/www/html/vendor/darrynten/clarifai-php/src/Entity' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/ctest.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Input' not found in
>   /var/www/html/ctest.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/ctest.php on line 11

The class Input is located at `/var/www/html/vendor/darrynten/clarifai-php/src/Entity` which I am including using the include keyword in PHP right after the first include, of no avail.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
include '/var/www/html/vendor/darrynten/clarifai-php/src/Entity';
```

Later, I used the following code

```
$concept = new \DarrynTen\Clarifai\Entity\Concept();
$concept->setId('boscoe')->setValue(true);

$input = new \DarrynTen\Clarifai\Entity\Input();
$input->setImage('https://samples.clarifai.com/puppy.jpeg')->isUrl()
    ->setConcepts([$concept]);

$inputResult = $clarifai->getInputRepository()->add($input);
```

on the last line, I am getting this error. (Guzzle related)

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
>   error: `POST https://api.clarifai.com/v2/inputs` resulted in a `400
>   Bad Request` response:
>   {"status":{"code":10020,"description":"Failure"},"inputs":[{"id":"e25be6bf0a4a4090a774694c016202cb","data":{"image":{"ur
>   (truncated...) in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:111
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65):
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1

Is this also name space related?

Comment: looks like it thinks Entity is a folder, but you state it contains a class, so presumably it's a file? That would explain the "Not a directory" error. Can this file be renamed to, for example, Entity.php? If it's a PHP file, it would be better to give it the proper extension. AFAIK you can't use `include` to specify a whole directory either.

Comment: `include '/var/www/html/vendor/darrynten/clarifai-php/src/Entity';` - what's this? You're using an autoloader, but you're including a **directory**. It looks like you mixed up what namespaces do and how autoloading works.

Comment: @Mjh To be honest yes. First time I am doing this.I appreciate honest feedback and any insight on what to do

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to use `darrynten/clarafai-php` package classes, right?

Comment: @mjh yes, that is the package I am using

Comment: First line is fine, you included the autoloader. After that what you do is instantiating each class you need by referencing its namespace. Example: `$clarafai = new DarrynTen\Clarifai\Clarafai;` -> open the `Clarafai.php` and look for `namespace` keyword. When you specify this namespace, autoloader calculates where it is and includes the file(s) for you.

Comment: @Mjh your tip worked. However, there is a new error now. I updated the question, please check the last part. Is this also namespace related? If so, I will answer the question myself and show corrected code.

Comment: It appears you're sending wrong input to the API. The code itself is functioning, you're getting `http` 400 back with a bunch of errors. It's up to you now to debug what's wrong and what exact input isn't being sent properly.

Comment: @tony9099 by assuming that the main problem is related to the incompatibility of this library with the new Clarifai `api_key` mechanism, I suggest you to take a look to my answer. Maybe it could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a new PHP library that seems to be compatible with **new apps** in Clarifai created with the new `api_key` version: [phpfanatic/clarifai](https://github.com/PHPfanatic/clarifai)

You can easily try to install it via composer:

```
composer require phpfanatic/clarifai
```

As dependencies you need to have:

- PHP - 5.6, 7.0 - May work with ealier version, untested at this time.
- cURL - *
- Clarifai API Key - clarifai
- PHPUnit - to run tests (optional).

[Here](https://github.com/PHPfanatic/clarifai/wiki) you can find the full documentation with **quick tutorial** or **step by step explanation**.

Answer (score 0):

Eddie from Clarifai here. Sorry you ran into an issue.

I see that you are using an API key. This community library currently only supports our [old auth mechanism](http://blog.clarifai.com/introducing-api-keys-a-safer-way-to-authenticate-your-applications/). All new "apps" in Clarifai are only created with an `api_key` as opposed to `client_id` and `client_secret`.

There's currently a [PR open](https://github.com/darrynten/clarifai-php/pull/46) to add support for API keys.

We're hoping to have first class PHP support by the end of the year.